# IntelliJ does not consider scala compiler options configured with maven

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scala-maven-plugin, intellij-scala

How can i tell IntelliJ to use the compiler options configured in maven's `net.alchim31.maven`/`scala-maven-plugin` plugin settings in my `pom.xml`?

#### Goal

I have a **Scala** setup with **Maven**. I use IntelliJ Idea as IDE.
My goal is to add integration tests with **Testcontainers** and **Spring Boot** which currently looks like this:

```scala
object IntegrationTest:
    private val database = new PostgreSQLContainer(DockerImageName.parse("postgres"))

    if DockerClientFactory.instance().isDockerAvailable then database.start()

    @DynamicPropertySource
    def databaseProperties(registry: DynamicPropertyRegistry): Unit =
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", () => database.getJdbcUrl)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", () => database.getUsername)
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", () => database.getPassword)
```

#### Problem

The scala compiler shows this error plus 5 similar errors:

```
scalac: possible data race involving globally reachable variable parameters in class JdbcDatabaseContainer: java.util.Map[String, String]
  use -Ylog:checkReentrant+ to find out more about why the variable is reachable.
```

#### Partial Fix

I was able to resolve it with a compiler option for test scope in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-Ysafe-init</arg>    <!-- this one -->
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Running `mvn test` in the console works just fine.

#### Remaining Problem

Executing any test or even the main application out of IntelliJ fails with the above error.

I also tried to add `-Ysafe-init` to `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Compiler` > `Scala Compiler` > `Additional compiler options`, but without success.